# Open Firefox with a temporary add-on on startup

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is there a way in which I can open Firefox and force it to load a temporary add-on (webextension) on startup? Normally I have to manually go to `about:debugging` and select the extension on my hard drive. I'm looking for a flag I can pass when I load Firefox so that this is done automatically.

If this is not possible, is there a recommended extension I can install to simulate that a user opens this URL and adds this extension?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use the command [`web-ext run`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/web-ext_command_reference#web-ext_run) from the directory in which the extension exists. This will start Firefox with the WebExtension installed using a temporary profile. `web-ext run` is intended for testing your WebExtension add-on during development, not for normal use of Firefox. By default, the `web-ext run` command will watch your WebExtension's files and [automatically reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext#Automatic_extension_reloading) the extension when any of the files are changed. You can disable this feature by using the [`--no-reload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/web-ext_command_reference#--no-reload) option.

If you are using a Firefox version below 49, you will need to specify the `--pre-install` option which uses a different method of installing the extension in the profile. However, if you use the `--pre-install`, your WebExtension will not be operational if you are trying to use a release or beta version of Firefox and the extension is not signed. This basically means that using `--pre-install` is not useful for Firefox versions below 49 unless you are using a Developer Edition build. Using `--pre-install` can be useful for Developer Edition versions of Firefox above 49 if you are wanting to test how your extension behaves during Firefox startup. If you do not use the `--pre-install` option, your extension is installed as a temporary extension and does not need to be signed to be tested in release versions of Firefox.

If you want to use a specific profile, then you need to specify the profile using the [`--firefox-profile`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/web-ext_command_reference#--firefox-profile_-p) option. [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext#Using_a_custom_profile):

> When using a custom profile, web-ext first copies the profile. The custom profile will not be altered.

### Installing `web-ext`

You will need to install `web-ext`. You can do so by following the instructions in [Getting started with web-ext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext).  The instructions are to, after you install [node/npm](https://nodejs.org/), run the following command:

```
npm install --global web-ext
```

### References

- [Getting started with web-ext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext)
- [web-ext command reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/web-ext_command_reference)

Comment: I don't know if it is me who didn't understand the question because I expected to load any addon on statup.